# WMI query in powershell script returns no object when run in a scheduled task

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, wmi

I have a powershell script that runs successfully.  I have tested it to death. The problem comes when running it as a scheduled task.  The WMI query returns no object.  I have tested with the a powershell console running under the context of the account used to run the scheduled task and it runs successfully under those conditions as well.  Only when running as a scheduled task does the WMI query fail.

```
...

Function getMSMQMessageCount($queueName) {
    Add-content $LogFile "Querying $queueName"

    $query = "SELECT MessagesinQueue FROM Win32_PerfRawData_MSMQ_MSMQQueue WHERE Name = '$queueName'"
    try{
        $wmiObject = Get-WmiObject -Query $query
        $wmiObject.MessagesinQueue
    }catch{
        Add-content $LogFile "MSMQ Enumeration error $($_.Exception)" 
    }
}

$messaging = getMSMQMessageCount 'server\\private$\\messaging.application'
```

Exception caught in the Function used to issue the query:

```
System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Property 'MessagesinQueue' cannot be found on this object. Make sure that it exists.
   at System.Management.Automation.PropertyReferenceNode.GetValue(PSObject obj, Object property, ExecutionContext context)
   at System.Management.Automation.PropertyReferenceNode.Execute(Array input, Pipe outputPipe, ExecutionContext context)
   at System.Management.Automation.ParseTreeNode.Execute(Array input, Pipe outputPipe, ArrayList& resultList, ExecutionContext context)
   at System.Management.Automation.StatementListNode.ExecuteStatement(ParseTreeNode statement, Array input, Pipe outputPipe, ArrayList& resultList, ExecutionContext context)
```

Comment: Samples should be short and simple. Can you remove 90% of the code which is unnecessary as far as I can tell? It will make it easier for us to see the real problem and more people will try to help you. If the problem is inside the `getMSMQMessageCount` function, then we only need that, the function that calls it and the parameters used with it. And exception ofc. like you have provided. :-)

Comment: Shortened the code example...people usually ask for everything...can't win

Comment: Looks good, thanks. To clarify: you should provide everything that matters, but keep it as minimal as possible. That's the rules, http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . :-) Ex. the function itself isn't enough since you're passing in a queuename-value, so we need that too. If that value was retrieved/generated using a different function, we would also need that. But we don't need all the export-logic, logging etc. if it fails long before those steps anyways.

Comment: I should note that this works without issue if running the task under the SYSTEM account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested your code, but it sounds like it requires administrator-rights to retrieve the data.

To use your account's administrator-rights, you need to check the `Run with highest privileges`-checkbox on the General page of the scheduled task. That is similar to answering yes in the UAC-dialog when you run it manually.

Comment: I did that.  I originally started this with an account that was a domain administrator.  The Local System account is the only one that works.  I could try making the account that I'm using now a local admin but we are trying to use the least permissions for the accounts that run tasks.

Comment: So when you tried a domain admin-account, did it work? Did you try the "highest priviliges"-checkbox? First get an account with local admin rights to work (give local admin rights and check Run with highest priviliges). When you have that working, then you could try to strip down the users rights. No matter what permissions you give, if the class requires elevated acces, then you still need to use the checkbox to bypass UAC/use your elevated rights. The SYSTEM account works without it because it's not a standard user account so it's no limited by a UAC.