# Get-WmiObject returns nothing in a PowerShell Script running as scheduled task

Tags: powershell, task, wmi, updates, scheduler

My entire script is about 800 lines long and contains a lot of other functionality so i will focus on the actual problem in this question.
I made a PowerShell script that uses the Get-WmiObject cmdlet to get the installed Windows Updates on the computer it runs on.
The full command looks like this:

```
$windowsupdates = Get-WmiObject Win32_QuickFixEngineering -ErrorAction Stop |
Select-Object Caption, CSName, Description, FixComments, HotFixID, InstallDate, InstalledBy, InstalledOn, Name, ServicePackInEffect, Status -ErrorAction Stop |
Sort-Object -Property InstallDate -ErrorAction Stop
```

After this command i iterate through the found updates via ForEach and generate a csv file from them.
This works entirely fine when running the script manually but as soon as i run it as scheduled task under the exact same user i used to run it manually it will no longer find any updates installed on the system.
There are no exceptions thrown and everything seems as if the script was running normal.
When i finish the script a scheduled task will be used to run it because it has to run in a specific time interval so i have to make sure it runs fine as scheduled task. The script will be running under a standard user without administrator permissions (i will not be able to run it under an administrator user so don't suggest me doing that, it DOES work on an administrator user though) so i'm sure it is a security/access problem because the script runs fine under an administrator user as scheduled task.
The only other question i found about this issue is [WMI query in powershell script returns no object when run in a scheduled task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28751730/wmi-query-in-powershell-script-returns-no-object-when-run-in-a-scheduled-task) and i DID check the "Run with highest privileges" Checkbox but it still doesn't work. Has anybody ever experienced this issue and knows a solution?

Comment: _i'm sure it is a security/access problem_ I wouldn't be so sure. Access denied means you get an exception, particularly with `-ErrorAction Stop`. It's hard to tell what exactly is going on w/o seeing the context but intuition suggests it's likely faulty logic. In other words: the line never gets to execute at all.

Comment: @AlexanderObersht where did i say anything about an "Access denied" error? By the way i already added nothing else than this line of code and an "Out-File" call in a standalone script and executed it as the (non-admin) user and as the same user via a scheduled task and the result was exactly the same: Manually executing it generated a valid csv file containing all the information i wanted while the file created via the scheduled task was empty (but has been created).